# TFS Team Explorer Everywhere gives "An input validation error occurred: The character ':' is not permitted in server paths."

Tags: tfs, team-explorer-everywhere

Currently cannot use tf get, tf status, tf checkin on a Unix box (using Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client version 12.0.2.201409181807) as I get the following error:

```
An input validation error occurred: The character ':' is not permitted in server paths.
```

When I look at remote workspaces on Visual Studio the Advanced edit shows the Server to be server_name\collection_name (pretty sure there is no ':' in there). I cannot find a way to show the server path the command line client is trying to use, nor can I find a way to change through the command line. Visual Studio is unable to change settings on a remote workspace.

Extensive searching of both Google and this website have produced no match for this error and I am at a loss as to what to do. Completely removing the workspace and starting again seems to work for a short time but this is definitely not a long term option.

Also having issues with Public workspaces. Every single time I have set the permissions to Public. Every single time I have benn ignored by the client.

Comment: This isn't about your workspace mappings, this suggests that you are trying to check in a file with a `:` in the name.  Can you show the pending changes list?

Comment: @Edward pendingchanges.lock is empty and `tf status` doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I made no changes except add a dummy file (with no ':' in the name)

Comment: @EdwardThomson The workspace has been mapped to an attached nas. This would have a : in it if the actual location of the nas is used rather than the mount location. This wouldn't explain why TEE worked briefly before failing though would it?

Comment: I would expect `pendingchanges.lock` to be empty.  I'd be interested to see your working folder mappings, and I'd be interested to know if a server workspace (versus a local workspace) changes the behavior.  This sounds like it may be a product bug.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yeah I had the `.lock` and `.tf1` file confused. The name of the pending file itself didn't have any colons. The problem seems to only occur when there is a mapping to the external file system. I've had an internally mounted project working on a different server for several weeks, yet this other one keeps packing in almost immediately. I then mapped a directory from the external drive on the previously working workspace and it gave the same error.. How might a server workspace change this?

Comment: I don't know, we may `stat`/`lstat` the file differently in the file system crawler that detects changes in local workspaces versus server.  Just more data about the problem (plus a possible workaround for now.)

Comment: It's working... for now. Will check back tomorrow. Thanks for your help!